# Visual Studio 2012 Platform Toolset set Incorrectly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, nmake

I have a C++ project that I created in VS 2010 and I'm now running it in 2012, but I still want to use the 2010 compiler. All my other projects in the same solution are fine but for some reason this one NMake file going to Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 for the MSBuild.exe instead of Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 like it is supposed to. Does Anyone know how to change this?

Normally I would just open the vcxproj and go to the platformtool set and change it from 11 to 10 but my NMake file won't allow that.

I think the problem is here -

```
ClCompile:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\CL.exe /c...
```

it should be

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\CL.exe /c...
```

But I can't figure out what I need to change to fix that.

I am also getting this error which I am just assuming is caused by this problem.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "call build_qt.bat win32" exited with code 1.
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I really can't figure this out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue, as I am using a QT project.  I can't target XP machines with our code due to this issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps your issue, but in order to fix my issue as described in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx

I modified my .pri/.pro file to include these values

```
win32 {  
  QMAKE_LFLAGS += /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01
  QMAKE_CXX += /D_USING_V110_SDK71_

  LIBS *= -L"%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/7.1A/Lib"

  INCLUDEPATH += "%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/7.1A/Include"
}
```

I also recompiled Qt 5.0 using those flags, just to be safe (although I don't think it was needed.