# GAMMU -- Identify: not a valid win32 application

Tags: gammu

I downloaded from official site and installed latest version of Gammu for windows.
The set-up runs just fine like any other exe I have ever installed.

Then, when I try to call the command as instructed in the official guide I get [this message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cmE-eWUuDfELIv-z-t23NnbIGeYqU20M/view?usp=sharing): ([alternative](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oG4XN4SoXnOyBqhs-OxZ99lSwqYUPObH/view?usp=sharing))

I've tried anything but it's always the same.

All of the other similar "win32 not a valid application" questions are related to self-made applications or programming in general: I haven't found a similar problem related to gammu in the whole web, [except for a very old case from seven years](http://miryadi.blogspot.it/2010/02/percobaan-setting-gammu-menggunakan.html) ago which suggest to downgrade, which of course I can't do.

any suggestion to this problem? anyone had a similar one

Comment: You're second one to complain about this on Gammu, so there is probably something wrong in our build system. Can you try if some older release will work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there seems to be problem with [running apps built with recent Visual studio on Windows XP and 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305659/225718).

Fortunately there is [a configuration to change this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14754251/225718).

I've just committed this change to Gammu and the [new binaries will soon build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nijel/gammu). They should be available for download [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nijel/gammu/build/515/job/4dgntr59xhb44qx3/artifacts). It would be great if you can test them...

Comment: Thanks very much. In fact I see now that artifacts tab is populated: it wasn't yet one hour ago. Thanks very much for your answer. I will try and get back asap

Comment: I've added direct link, otherwise you probably always look at current build which is building :-). - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nijel/gammu/build/515/job/4dgntr59xhb44qx3/artifacts

Comment: allora, thanks very much @Michal because now it works!! I've been able to correctly connect to the modem and see the same screen in cmd that I read in the quick start guide. The problem is now that I am not able to send or receive sms, even if it says ok. I need to work on this. But in the meantime thank you for your solution!

Comment: Thanks for testing, next Gammu release will come with this fix.